# Full track playback on free subscription

Tags: ios7, streaming, spotify, playlist

Suppose my app accesses (publicly visible) playlists on Spotify. And wants to play (stream) the entire playlist on a user's device. 
1 ) I am assuming the user will need to have an account (will need to be authenticated)?
2) Can the AUTHENTICATED user - with their FREE spotify account - be able to get full playback of all the tracks?

Thanks - that's the bulk of my question. Although, I would like to know if there is an iOS specific SDK as well.

Thanks
AV

Answer (score 0):

There's an [iOS SDK (Beta)](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/).

The user who is authenticated through your application needs to have a Premium account.

> Play an audio stream from Spotify. (Premium accounts only)
>   - [iOS SDK Tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks. That helps. 

Now, let us say the user (user A) configured to use the app - IS a premium user.

Another  user (user B) downloads app - fires it up. The app still uses (authenticates using user A's credentials).   

So - user B should be able to stream as well - using A's premium acct.
Is my understanding correct ?  

Thanks

Comment: Well, yes, since user B doesn't exist as far as Spotify is concerned. However, only one device can stream at a time even if they're signed in the the same user. Additionally, shipping an app that actively promotes this sort of thing (streaming music to multiple unrelated users using one Spotify account) is likely to get your app a cease and desist pretty quickly.

Comment: I understand. See - I am happy to pay additional for the SINGLE PREMIUM account - a sort of MULTI-user account if you will. All I am trying to do is either

Comment: Got truncated. What I am after is a way for users to play FULL soundtracks with their FREE accounts. It seems that streaming services restrict users to 30 second clips with their free accounts. Thanks for your feedback - if you happen to know of any service that offers full playback on non-premium accounts, I would appreciate your advice.